# How to make navigation by buttons on web site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do make navigation like [here](http://secretstudy.ca/)?
I am interesting in transitions between screens. Animation and other are not important.
It will be wonderful, get link to complete library or some tutorials.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use history API to achieve this. history.js can help you for this:
https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `Navigation` using `arrow Keys` and also with `mouse gestures`,

Then their is a `Plugin` that helps you to make `Transitions`,As well as Performs Smooth animations .

## Impress.js

*Link below :*

[**Impress.js**](http://bartaz.github.io/impress.js/#/bored)

This is very popular to make `presentations`,May it helps you to achieve your task .